# Breakdown of map time in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I wanted to know how the mapper time is calculated in hadoop. I noted the time in map setup() method and map cleanup() method for each map task and the difference would have been the mapper time. But when I go to my job tracker page and analyze the job the time shown for the mapper is different and is higher than the difference value which I got previously. Can someone explain me this anomaly